# How do I store the printed numbers from this function into a list (Python)?

Tags: python

```
a = 0
def multipleThree(n):
    while a < n:
        global a
        a = a + 3
        print (a, end= ' ')

multipleThree(100)
```

This just prints out a bunch of numbers, but I want to save `3,6,9...102` into a list. I know that something like `listName = []` or something will probably be used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
a = 0
my_list = []
def multipleThree(n):
    while a < n:
        global a
        a = a + 3
        my_list.append(a)
        print (a, end= ' ')    
multipleThree(100)

print my_list
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [*list comprehension*](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/):

```
def multipleThree(n):
    return [a for a in xrange(3, n + 4, 3)]
```

The `xrange()` here starts at `3`, and ends at `n+3`, and increments by `3` on each iteration.

This will return a list.

You can then do this:

```
multiples = multipleThree
print(*multiples)
```

(Or `print *multiples`) for Python 2.7.x.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! If this answers your question, click the "accept answer" checkbox next to the answer.